# How to group options in Filter Panel on Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I'm wondering how to group some values in a filter panel in Qlik Sense

For Example:
In a filter pane we have:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
Item4
```

But `Item3` and `Item4` I want to group it just into a 1 `ItemX2`

So finally it will be:

```
Item1
Item2
ItemX2
```

How can I do this in Qlik Sense?

I was trying with `match()` or `aggr()` but I wasn't so lucky

Answer (score 1):

This is a data issue. Try not to solve such problems in the frontend/UI. Especially in apps with a lot of data. Such solutions are going to reduce the performance (more aggregations on the fly)

In the script you can use [ApplyMap](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2019/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/MappingFunctions/ApplyMap.htm) function to create such grouping

(For example) In the script below the have [Mapping](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2019/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/Mapping.htm) table contains all `Items` that are requiring re-mapping (grouping in your case)

This table is used to create new field (`ItemsGrouped`) which will contain the new values (if the `Items` field is not a key to another table you can overwrite it with the `ApplyMap` instead of creating new field). This field can be shown in the UI and will contain these values:

```
Item1
Item2
ItemX2
```

```
ItemsMapping:
Mapping
Load * Inline [
Old  , New
Item3, ItemX2
Item4, ItemX2
];

Data:
Load
  ....
  Items,
  ApplyMap('ItemsMapping', Items) as ItemsGrouped
From
  MyData.qvd
;
```